# $(X_k)_k$ Random Walk, Law of $(|X_k|)_k$ can be expressed as law of modified maximumprocess

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, random-walk

Let $(X_k)_{k\in \mathbb N_0}$ be a simple random walk on $\mathbb Z$ and $M_k := \max \{X_1,\ldots,X_k\}$, the maximum process. Then $Y_k := M_k - X_k$ is a Markov chain. By $\sigma_0 = 0, \sigma_m := \inf\{ l> \sigma_{m-1} : Y_l \neq  Y_{l-1} \}$ denote the $m$th time of movement of $(Y_k)_k$. So by defining $$\tilde{Y}_m := Y_{\sigma_m}$$
we remove the flat steps from $(Y_k)_k$.
What I want to show is:
$$\mathcal{L}((|X_k|)_{k\in\mathbb N_0}) = \mathcal{L}((\tilde Y_k)_{k\in\mathbb N_0}),$$
where $\mathcal L$ denotes the laws of the processes.

My attempt was to use sort of reflection principle for random walks, but I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Markov chains $\{|X_k|\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ and $\{\tilde{Y}_m\}_{m=0}^{\infty}$  both have the same state space and the same transition probabilities. Specifically, if $|X_k|=0$ then $|X_{k+1}|=1$ with prob 1, and likewise if $\tilde{Y}_m=0$ then $\tilde{Y}_{m+1}=1$ with prob 1.  Now if $|X_k|>0$ then on the next step it is equally likely to move either up or down, and the same holds for $\tilde{Y}_m$.

Comment: So simple. Thank you.